# Cyclic dependency detected when creating index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am attempting to index my mongodb documents (tweets) to optimize search time on my query, I am using compass to build it and I am getting a "Cyclic dependency detected" error.

The fields I am attempting to index are as follows:
(user is an object)

- user.screen_name (string)
- user.lang (string)
- user.locale (string)
- user.groups (array)
- full_text (string)
- entities.hashtags.text (entities: object, hashtags: array, text: string)
- entities.user_mentions.screen_name (user_mentions: array of objects, screen_name:string
- retweeted_status (object)
- is_quote_status (bool)
- entities.media (media: array of objects)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these fields all part of the same single index definition?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, they are.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6109

Comment: I would suggest you remove one field after the other and see which one causes the problem.